# reassigning xarray data variable to xarray coordinate

Tags: python, dataframe, netcdf, python-xarray

I have a pandas dataframe of spatial data that I would like to convert to a netCDF. I have found my way to xarray and converted my dataframe into an xarray dataset:

```
# create xray Dataset from Pandas DataFrame
xr = xarray.Dataset.from_dataframe(df)
```

Now, I want to set the `lon` and `lat` variables as the coordinates of my xarray dataset.
I have tried `xarray.Dataset.assign_coords` but cant seem to get it to work?

My xarray dataset looks like:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (index: 58705)
Coordinates:
  * index    (index) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 ... 58699 58700 58701 58702 58703 58704
Data variables:
    x_km     (index) float64 5.274e+03 5.273e+03 ... 2.873e+03 2.873e+03
    y_km     (index) float64 0.0 46.02 92.03 138.0 ... -75.23 -50.15 -25.07 -0.0
    z_km     (index) float64 3.575e+03 3.575e+03 ... 1.947e+03 1.947e+03
    dv_v     (index) float64 0.2407 0.1774 0.1786 ... -0.2163 -0.2035 -0.3197
    rxy      (index) float64 5.274e+03 5.273e+03 ... 2.873e+03 2.873e+03
    lon      (index) float64 0.0 0.5 1.0 1.5 2.0 ... -2.0 -1.5 -1.0 -0.5 -0.0
    lat      (index) float64 34.13 34.13 34.13 34.13 ... 34.11 34.12 34.12 34.13
    rxyz     (index) float64 6.371e+03 6.371e+03 ... 3.471e+03 3.471e+03
    depth    (index) float64 0.04665 0.04747 0.04766 ... 2.9e+03 2.9e+03 2.9e+03
Attributes:
    Conventions:  CF-1.6
    title:        Data
    summary:      Data generated
```

Any help is appreciated :D

Comment: can't you set `lon` and `lat` in the dataframe and then create the xarray?

Comment: how would you do that?

Comment: can you show your dataframe

Comment: To reiterate what @Kenan is saying, try using a mutii-index df with lon and lat.  Try `df.set_index(['lon','lat])` before converting to xarray.

Answer (score 7):

Starting from a `Dataset` called `ds` that looks like this:

```
Dimensions:  (index: 10)
Coordinates:
  * index    (index) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
Data variables:
    dv_v     (index) int64 5 14 6 1 19 12 16 10 0 11
    rxy      (index) int64 15 8 6 2 0 1 4 16 7 19
    lon      (index) int64 15 7 9 17 18 1 12 2 6 8
    lat      (index) int64 6 8 5 17 15 16 9 19 11 14
    rxyz     (index) int64 15 17 18 5 14 13 16 2 10 9
    depth    (index) int64 11 18 5 19 3 14 7 17 0 4
```

You can convert `lat` and `lon` to coordinates with `ds.set_coords(("lat", "lon"))`. The result would be the following:

```
Dimensions:  (index: 10)
Coordinates:
  * index    (index) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
    lon      (index) int64 15 7 9 17 18 1 12 2 6 8
    lat      (index) int64 6 8 5 17 15 16 9 19 11 14
Data variables:
    dv_v     (index) int64 5 14 6 1 19 12 16 10 0 11
    rxy      (index) int64 15 8 6 2 0 1 4 16 7 19
    rxyz     (index) int64 15 17 18 5 14 13 16 2 10 9
    depth    (index) int64 11 18 5 19 3 14 7 17 0 4
```

Another similar (but not equivalent) alternative is to use `ds.set_index(index=("lat", "lon"))` which will modify `index` to a multilevel index with indexes `lat` and `lon`. The output would be the following:

```
Dimensions:  (index: 10)
Coordinates:
  * index    (index) MultiIndex
  - lat      (index) int64 6 8 5 17 15 16 9 19 11 14
  - lon      (index) int64 15 7 9 17 18 1 12 2 6 8
Data variables:
    dv_v     (index) int64 5 14 6 1 19 12 16 10 0 11
    rxy      (index) int64 15 8 6 2 0 1 4 16 7 19
    rxyz     (index) int64 15 17 18 5 14 13 16 2 10 9
    depth    (index) int64 11 18 5 19 3 14 7 17 0 4
```

Comment: When I do this, I can't use `Dataset.sel()` to find elements.  I get an error that "dimensions or multi-index levels do not exist." AFAICT, this is because the coordinates are not dimensions.  Could you expand this answer to tell us how the coordinates become usable dimensions of the data variables?

Comment: I could extend it to show how to convert coords to dims, or would it be better to use `where` caluses? It is currently not possible to index using non-dimension coordinates: https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/2028

Comment: However, it looks like support for that is on the roadmap: https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/1603